# Get a 2D Array into a datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I want to get my 2D Array in a datatabe and then get the datatable in a datagridview
Here is the code I work with right now:

In my Main:

```
            string[,] values = new string[numbersOfRows, numbersOfColumns];
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfColumns; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(values[0, i]);
            }

            for (int j = 2; j < numbersOfRows; j++)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfColumns; i++)
                {
                    row[i] = values[j, i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            Datagridview dgv = new Datagridview(dt);
            dgv.Show();
```

the cw does not display the rows
In my datagridview:

```
public Datagridview(DataTable dt)
{
    dgv_schedule.DataSource = dt.DefaultView; //here I get the exception
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

What am I doing wrong, when I run the programm I get a `"System.NullReferenceException"`

Comment: @MBakardzhiev umdated the code get the exception in dgv_schedule.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize dgv_schedule before accessing any of its properties. When you try to access a reference type's properties when it is null, you get NullReferenceException.

By the way, don't concatenate strings inside a loop, because you create a new string each time, thus you put the GC on pressure and waste memory. Use the class [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead to concatenate strings.